# how to store with phonegap cordova on offline mode

Tags: cordova, local-storage, phonegap-plugins, offline-caching, offlineapps

Let's say we have an android app built with Phone gap (builder)
converting currencies, I wish the app to store the latest currency when online over local machine? the app written with php, should I use mysql database or do you suggest other method for storing such information.
Is there specific plugin written for such use? 
I want lets say 5 currencies to be stored and updated each time the app is launched

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for noting , I couldn't find another way to explain the question as there's no code asked about

Comment: You are welcome. But this is not a question typically asked on stackoverflow. It is too broad in my opinion. 
But lmgtfy: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/storage/storage.html#page-toc-source

Comment: You say your app is written with PHP? Do know that PGB is not a server, and as such has no mechanism for dealing with client-side PHP.

As for storage, the File API would almost certainly be sufficient. `localStorage` is tempting, but it's not guaranteed to be persistent and other storage mechanisms are overkill for your needs (for example, SQLite, but do you really need the power of a database for five values? No, probably not.)

Comment: @KerriShotts the app works fine written with PHP, JS, jquery mobile and so client works well. (google api) using the phonegap builder.I will check your tips. regarding a database its seems natural to use a table for daily changing currency. could be overkill to use SQlite..

Comment: Are you wrapping a website? If so, know that Apple will reject the app, and Google may as well. PhoneGap isn't intended to wrap remote code -- the intent is to bring your UI code local and use XHR to communicate with your backend.

If you were handling a a lot of currency values, then I'd suggest a table. For five? There's no reason to consider a database at all, unless you have plans to increase that number significantly in the future. It's trivial to use the File API to dump an array and load it back in, and that will be far less overhead than any database engine.